# apple script to check user name and password when connecting to smb share

Tags: macos, networking, applescript, share, smb

```
-- Applescript to ask for username/password. repeats if incorrect.
repeat

-- Ask for user name
set userName to text returned of (display dialog "enter your user name" with title "User Name" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Okay"} default button 2)

-- Asks for password    
set myPassword to text returned of (display dialog "enter your password" with title "User Name" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Okay"} default button 2 with hidden answer)

-- Sets users network share path    
set userShare to "smb://" & userName & ":" & myPassword & "@ourserver/usershare/" & userName & ""


try
    -- Attempts to mount the above location
    mount volume userShare
    -- This where the script pauses on the OSX connect to server prompt


    --checks to see if users share is mounted in /volumes/
    if " & userName & " is in (do shell script "/bin/ls /volumes") then
        --exits loop
        exit repeat
    end if
end try
end repeat
```

I maintain an iMac lab and the instructors now have need for students to use a local account, but access their network share. The iMacs are joined to Active Directory, but in this scenario the kids are logging in as a generic local "student" account.

I have an applescript that ask for the users user name and password, but really only works if the user name and password provided are correct. Other wise, the "connect to server" prompt launches when a user name or password is entered incorrectly.

I am trying to see if there is a way to handle this prompt, or skip it entirely if the user name entered is incorrect. The prompt seems to basically 'Pause' the script at the moment. If I press cancel, the script starts up again and the user can re-enter username and password.

This is being used by young elementary students, so limiting errors is helpful to the instructor.

Any ideas? I think what I am looking for is a way to pass credentials to our server, see if they are correct, and then attempt mounting the network share.

Comment: I think the issue is instruction "mount volume server". the word server is not defined. you don't get script error, because you're in block 'try'. I suggest to change to "mount volume UserShare". (UserShare is defined line above).

Comment: I made some edits to my original file to make the names a bit more generic for question purposes, and missed one. Edited to have the right name here.

Comment: since your edit, i it now working as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding what I was looking for by using ldapsearch to bind to AD and authenticate user names and passwords.